# while loop inserting same value in table

Tags: php

I can't figure out what is wrong with my logic here. The first query returns four items ( I confirmed that). I want to insert these ids in another table. Four inserts occur but all with the first id only. What is wrong here?

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE item IN (".$x.") ORDER by id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$sqq = "INSERT INTO table2 (item1, item2, item3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqq);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $it1, $it2, $row);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Which column contains the same value? `item3`?

Comment: It is not a good idea to run queries in a loop, you can do it in one query.

Comment: Yes, the last one. item3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`fetch_object()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) returns an object, but you're trying to use it as an integer. You should use `$row->id` to get the value.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $it1, $it2, $row->id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.

Comment: @Furgas I think the implicit conversion to integer casted the object to `1`.

Comment: Error logs showed : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int